# imagecreatefrompng() and size limitation

Tags: php, gd, imagecreatefrompng

I have some troubles with the function **imagecreatefrompng()**, in PHP.

I develop a website which has the goal to permit users to upload their own Sprite Comics (kinds of Comics made with ressources extracted from videogames, called sprites).

I want to display in their galeries some miniatures of their comics, so I use GD and, of course, **imagecreatefrompng()**.

But it throw a fatal error with large images:

> **Fatal error**: Out of memory (allocated 8388608) (tried to allocate
>   4545600 bytes)

The same error occurs even after setting the value of "memory_limit" via **ini_set()**...

After few hours of researches, it seems to be because of the resolution: **imagecreatefrompng()** can't manage images having more than 1 040 000 pixels...!

It's very very inconvenient, since I can't limit the size of comics sent by the users...

Do you know any tips to resolve this issue?

Thnaks in advance!

Comment: Consider using Flash as your method of handling the images, would take away some of the server load and you won't have those limitations. Just an idea, never done it and don't know whether it's actually possible.

Comment: I don't like the idea of using Flash, but if I have to... Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask your hosting provider to set more virtual memory. It's a setting in `php.ini`   - `memory_limit` and shouldn't be problem to do it free. You are now on the most lowest value.

Comment: It seems to not be because of "memory_limit" : my default value is 90Mb, so I think it's enough :/ But thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think I am right. Must know, each pixel is in memory multiplied by picture bit depth. 1 000 000 pixels means aprox. image 1024 x 768 px. 16bit depth need to alocate min 16 Mb of memory for basic load. While resizing or other manipulating there is in use a copy of the same size. Real needed memory for image operation is much higher than it seems. There is still koeficent 1,5 - 2 in use for multiply the bit count result.